# How do I programmatically change the selected month in JQuery datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a jQuery datepicker and I cannot figure out how to programmatically change the month back to the current month. After making a `POST` request to save the user's dates I need to return the calendar back to the current month. The calendar may be on a different month from the user playing around with different dates. I have tried setting the `mindate` again but that did not work.

This is not a popup calendar.

Comment: how do you submit your form? normally direct submit or ajax?

Comment: @Rami.Q I use `ajax`. This is why I am having the issue. Because the state does not change.

Comment: then on ajax success do setDate as adeneo wrote in the answer

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting the datepicker back to today

```
$('#myDatePicker').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

setting just the month back

```
var date = $('#myDatePicker').datepicker('getDate');

date.setMonth( (new Date()).getMonth() );

$('#myDatePicker').datepicker('setDate', date);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/5Hbs3/)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `.val()` to set the date

```js
$("#datepicker").val(date);
```